# How to make Spik3r move without the pincers moving

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming

How do you make Spik3r move without the pincers moving as well? Seems like the legs are only controlled by the motor on port B, but the move tank and steer modules only allow for the use of 2 ports. Using ports B and C (vacant) results in an error, while there appears to be no way to tell the motor on port A (pincers) to not to move when ports A & B are selected.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Move Tank or Move Steer blocks. Use the Large Motor block for controlling a single motor instead.